# TextEditor Poor Performance in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a app in SwiftUI for macOS, and i'm using the TextEditor view in SwiftUI. I have a State variable that is adding new words constantly, and because of this the TextEditor ends up rendering 1000+ words. The TextEditor is not editable, and thus is using .constant(var)

There is not a lot of information on this, but I have looked at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672909, but there did not seem to be any good information on it. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var smallText = ""
    @State var text = ""
    @State var started = false
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.01, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GroupBox {
                ScrollViewReader { scroller in
                    ScrollView {
                        TextEditor(text: .constant(text))
                            .id(0)
                            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                            .scrollDisabled(true)
                            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                                if started {
                                    
                                    let random = Int.random(in: 0...1)
                                    
                                    if random == 0 {
                                        smallText = "100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters "
                                    } else {
                                        smallText = "100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 leters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters 100 letters "
                                    }
                                    
                                    text.append(smallText)
                                    
                                    withAnimation {
                                        scroller.scrollTo(0, anchor: .bottom)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(started ? "End" : "Begin") {
                started.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then start spamming keys, the app wont freeze up like it does in the main app (mainly because its not doing the intensive tasks that my app does) but it should get the point across when you try to hit the End button. You will notice its very, very delayed.

I have a M1 Pro with 16GB of ram.

Comment: Why not use UKit? SwiftUI has many performance issues with large datasets. All is this forcing seems to be harder than just using the right tool. What is the point of using constant for a TextEditor?

Comment: Constant binding is designed for previews. Why aren't you using `Text`?

Comment: Text is even worse performance wise hence the usage of TextEditor, and as for UIKit, i'm using macOS, but I will look into that and see, thanks for the tip @loremipsum

Comment: You can use AppKit in that case with an NSViewRepresentable to bridge the 2

Comment: I just implemented it, and its perfectly smooth, i'll make a answer right now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @loremipsum I was able to fix the problem.

SwiftUI's Text and TextEditor views can't handle a lot of text before it starts lagging the app out, so we have to implement a TextEditor in AppKit instead.

```
struct BetterTextEditor: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    var textView = NSTextView.scrollableTextView()
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSScrollView {
        let documentView = (textView.documentView as! NSTextView)
        
        documentView.backgroundColor = .textBackgroundColor
        documentView.delegate = context.coordinator
        documentView.isEditable = true
        
        let scroll = NSScrollView()
        scroll.hasVerticalScroller = true
        scroll.documentView = documentView
        scroll.drawsBackground = false
        
        return scroll
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: NSScrollView, context: Context) {
        let documentView = (view.documentView as? NSTextView)
        
        documentView?.string = text
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate{
        
        var parent: BetterTextEditor
        
        init(_ parent: BetterTextEditor) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else { return }
            
            self.parent.text = textView.string
        }
        
        func textView(_ textView: NSTextView, shouldChangeTextIn affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String?) -> Bool { return true }
    }
}
```

Which we can use just like the normal TextEditor!

Note: Do not wrap this inside a scroll view, or it will break, had to deal with that myself :)